# SQL запрос, который учитывает несколько условий

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Суть:

Есть таблица с заявками (orders)

id,
status

Есть таблица с материалами к заявкам (materials)

id,
mat,
num,
id_order,
status

Нужно прописать запрос, который бы выводил кнопку, на странице заявки, когда все его материалы имели определенный статус

К примеру, есть несколько материалов где id_order = 3, и статус у всех = 5, если все так, то выводим кнопку, но если хотя бы у одного статус не 5, то не выводить ничего

Если есть решение, при котором статус заявки меняется автоматически если все материалы имеют нужный статус, то было бы вообще замечательно.

Comment: `HAVING 0 = SUM(status != 5)`

Comment: *решение, при котором статус заявки меняется автоматически если все материалы имеют нужный статус* Триггер на таблице материалов.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, сейчас прочитаю про триггеры